# Change spell check language in the Windows 10 mail app for whole email

Tags: email, language, windows-mail, windows-10-mail-app

I have an issue with Windows 10 Mail app, with changing the language for spell check.

My system is set up in German, so this is the default setting when writing mails. But every now and then, I have to write an Email in English.

I can change the spell check language via options > spell check. But this setting only applies to the currently selected text! When I'm writing new text, the spell check language is changed back to German! Also, when I havn't selected anything and change spell check to English, new text is again checked in German!

The issue is not with the spell-check itself, but with auto-correction. In German, every noun is capitalized. And that's what happens here (e.g. "The folder is empty" => "The Folder is empty")

So how can I change the language in Mail for a whole mail?

Answer (score 4):

It is important to first set the language Windows key + Space bar before start writing or answering a message. Mid-message language changes are not possible

Comment: This is not correct. In fact, the Mail app has a nasty bug in certain circumstances that I can't pin down. I have my system in English, though I also have several other locales/keyboards installed, notably French but also Spanish and Chinese. I have no idea where this is coming from but if I paste a URL from any browser copied from the URL bar (at least Chrome, Edge and FF) then everything that gets typed after will get spellchecked in French. Yes, really! 

It can also be changed intentionally, see https://superuser.com/a/1038844/247938

Answer (score 2):

I recently bought a new laptop and because the model is new it wasnt available in my country, or at least not with the good specs. So I bought it via Amazon from Germany and had to change the language. I followed this "how to" and it seems it worked fine!

**How to change the language globally on your PC**

*Before we dive into this guide, it's important to note that if you're using a Microsoft Account, this preference will sync across devices. If you only want to change settings on one particular computer, you should go to 
Settings > Accounts > Sync your settings 
and turn off the Language preferences option.*

1. Use the Windows key + I keyboard shortcut to open the Settings app.
2. Click Time & language.
3. Click Region & language.
4. Under Languages, click Add a language.
5. Click the language you want to add, and select the specific
   variation if applicable.
6. Select the new language and click Options (and download any the
   language packs as necessary).
7. On Region & language, select the new language, and click Set as
   default.
8. If applicable, under Country or region, select your location to
   enable the Windows 10 to give you local content.
9. Use the Windows key + X keyboard shortcut to open the Power User
   menu and select Control Panel.
10. Click Add a language.
11. Click the Advanced settings link in the left pane.
12. Click the "Apply language settings to the Welcome screen, system
     accounts, and new user accounts."
13. On the Administrative tab, under the "Welcome screen and new user
     accounts", click the Copy settings button.
14. Check the Welcome screen and system accounts and the New user
     accounts options.
15. Click OK.
16. Click OK again.
17. Reboot your computer and upon restart, you should see the new
     default language globally set through the operating system.

*You'll find this feature especially useful when you work on a mixed-language environment where you need to configure workstations with different preferences to accommodate users. In addition, this feature will help in those times when you happen to purchase a new computer that ships from another country with a different language, or even when you move to another region of the world and you want to change your PC preferences to match the local settings.*

Source: http://www.windowscentral.com/how-properly-change-system-default-language-windows-10

Maybe it can work for you to. Make sure to change the whole system language to English for it to work. Maybe you do not want to do this but its at least one way of getting it to work.

Comment: This is a lengthy answer that doesn't address the question at all. The OP didn't ask how to change language in windows. They asked how to change the spell checker in _mail_.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the language of an e-mail by changing the keyboard language. If you have multiple keyboard languages set up, you can switch with <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>Space bar</kbd>.

I figured this out after reading this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1038844/31930.

Comment: Unfortunately Windows+ Space has no effect on my Windows 10 installation. The spell-check language stays English. I

Comment: @user: Make sure you have multiple keyboard languages set up. Windows will only switch keyboards if it has one setup to switch to.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, Mail app will sync and take the language from System language, which is 
set as default. The same applies for the auto correction option while sending an 
email from Mail app. I mean, the auto correction option will work accordingly as
per the default system language and provide suggestions for correcting the words.

In view of the same, to get suggestions or proofing in Spanish for the content 
which is typed in the Email app, you should set Spanish as default system
language. Navigate to Start, select Settings >Time & Language >Region &
language. Under Language, click Add a language and select the appropriate 
language. Go back to the “Time & Language” screen and click on the language you
just installed and select “Set as default”, and reboot your PC.

Comment: So you’re saying that the only way the OP can do what they want  is to reboot **twice** every time they want to write an email in English?