# How to set proofing language regardless the keyboard layout on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, spell-check, input-languages, proofing

On my Windows 10 I am using 3 different keyboard layouts. Whenever I type something in some application the operating system is matching the proofing language for spelling and grammar check with the language of the keyboard layout in use: for example, when I am using the ENG keyboard layout then English is used as proofing language.

It's often the case though that I am using the keyboard layout of my physical keyboard, even when I am writing in a language different from the one of the keyboard.

How do I tell the operating system, to use a specific language for proofing, regardless the keyboard layout?

Comment: @BožoStojković my question is about Windows, not OneNote.

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Go to settings > Region & Language.
2. In "Languages" > Add a language.
3. Add the language that you want to use for language proofing.
4. Click on that new added language and hit "options".
5. Add the keyboard layout that you want.
6. Switch proofing languages with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Comment: It does not seem to answer the question on how to set the proofing language **regardless the keyboard layout**

Comment: In fact it is the answer, I'm showing how to have any keyboard layout and a different proofing language.

Comment: Alt+shift switches both keyboard layout and proofing language. I do not want to switch keyboard layout. That's why it is specified "regardless of the keyboard layout".

Comment: Let me explain, my problem is that I've a ENG keyboard but most of the time I write in Spanish, but sometimes (like right now) I write in English.
So I had one language (Eng) installed with my English keyboard, so when I write in Spanish everything is marked as spelling error.
Then what I did was add Spanish to windows itself in [ settings > Region & Language ] and for that new language I added the English (UE International) language.
Now I've two proofing languages with the same keyboard layout, I really think it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Registry Editor **you can remove the unwanted keyboard layouts without removing the language pack as a whole**.

1. In Start menu type `regedit` and hit enter to open it.
2. Backup the values under the following entry, by navigating 'File -> Export'

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload
```

3. Then remove the values as you desire. These are non descriptive integers (1, 2, 3, etc.), but seem to correspond to the order in which your keyboard layouts are defined.

I'm imagining something similar may be possible for proofing. Some [AutoHotkey script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/RegWrite.htm) could possibly automate modifying these registry entries at wish.

---

*Note: despite not directly addressing the question in hand, I'm leaving this answer here as I think this is useful info regarding managing the language and keyboard settings on Windows, and could be used to mitigate the problem described.*

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings > Region & Language.

In "Keyboard and Languages" > click Change Keyboard.

Click "Add" Button

click the "+ button for the language that you want to spell check in".

Then Click "+ keyboard"

Now "+ Show More" option tick button

Select the keyboard you have.

Now click "ok" and you are done.

You can then also move you alternate keyboard language up into default position by clicking on it and clicking "Move Up".

so you could have English language with Spanish keyboard or vice versa.

Hope this helps FYI I was in win 7 Thanks